# Сформировать запрос

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с колонками brand,code,name,po1,price,pos2
Необходимо выбрать из таблицы строки, у который brand+code повторяются не более 2 раз. Исходная таблица
    
    `MKT 100 vagon  12 14.3 2
    MKT 100 vagon2 13 14.3 22 
    MKT 100 vagon3 14 14.3 21
    MKT 100 vagon4 15 14.3 2
    AKT 150 cars   12 14.3 2
    KVG 120 tops   12 14.3 2`

В рез-те мы должны получить
    
    `MKT 100 vagon  12 14.3 2
    MKT 100 vagon2 13 14.3 22
    AKT 150 cars   12 14.3 2
    KVG 120 tops   12 14.3 2`

Answer (score 0):

Нумеруем записи в пределах brand, code и выбираем первые 2:

```
select * from (
   select A.*,
          @n:=if(@g=concat(brand,code),@n+1,1) N,
          @g:=concat(brand,code)
     from tableX A, (select @g:='') B
    order by brand, code
  ) A
 where N<=2
```

Сортировка должна начинаться с колонок, участвующих в "группировке" для правильного подсчета. И не помешало бы добавить в сортировку еще какие либо колонки потому как иначе никаких гарантий того, какие именно 2 записи будут выбраны, нет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Данные сформировались, но неверно - нужных строк теперь только одна, какое бы условие я не писал (N<=5 дает тоже что N<=2)

Comment: @IK Для начала выполните внутренний подзапрос и посмотрите как именно пронумеровались строки. Вы в точности скопировали порядок присвоения переменных в запросе, сначала должен формироваться N и только после него в @g должна cохранятся текущая связка brand-code. И сортировка должна собрать подряд все записи с одной группой.

Comment: @IK сделал таблицу с вашими данными ... Запрос работает верно http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27f50f/1

Comment: '
select brand, code, name, pos1, price, pos2 from (
    select A.*,
     @n:=if(@g=concat(brand,code),@n+1,1) N,
     @g:=concat(brand,code)
    from temp_price A, (select @g:='') B
    order by brand, code, price
   ) A
    where N<=2
'

Comment: @IK То что вы написали дает тот результат который вы просили, на тех данных, что в вопросе. Если что то не так, приведите в sqlfiddle.com пример и напишите что не так в его выдаче

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. Но мне не удалось заставить скрипт работать как мне нужно. Поэтому оставил идею сделать это средствами чисто sql и подключил php. Тема закрыта

Answer (score 0):

Для решения НАПИСАННОЙ задачи подойдёт запрос

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE (`brand`, `code`) 
    IN (SELECT `brand`, `code`
        FROM `table`
        GROUP BY `brand`, `code`
        HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
       );
```

Но вот пример (вернее, эталонный ответ) решает другую задачу - для каждой пары brand+code оставить не более 2 записей. И очень хочется спросить - а если в группе записей больше двух, Вам всё равно, какие 2 записи из них будут выведены?