# Выборка 3 строк с каждого уникального значения столбца

Tags: mysql

Как сделать выборку за один запрос собрав по три строки с максимальными значения `points` с каждого уникального `divs`?

[image]

Comment: подзапросом придется пронумеровать в порядке убывания points, а потом выбрать первые 3 для каждой группы. Так что тут скорее за 2 запроса, а не за один.

Comment: @teran ,
Спасибо за ответ.
Это само собой ORDER BY `points` DESC LIMIT 3.
Вот только как составить запрос?))

Comment: Вот только вчера вечером вопрос был ... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585109/%D0%A1%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81/585127#585127   там чуть сложнее, там по 2 полям. вам надо вместо concat двух полей использовать свое divs ...

Comment: @Sashka66Rus Ну как, тот запрос не помог ? А то я уже подумываю по дублю вопрос закрывать ... они же почти одинаковые ...

Comment: @Mike не совсем. Либо я просто не вкуриваю)).
с sql особого опыта работы нет, только селект инсерт, да апдэйт. Читаю руководство mysql)).
здесь я еще привел простой пример, а по факту мне нужно получить многомерный массив(5 в глубину).
Сейчас у меня выборка через union - куча запросов из за того что я не могу группировать выборку(concat почти то что нужно, но он тоже не лимитируется) с limit ом 3 в каждой группе

Comment: @Sashka66Rus concat как раз совершенно не нужен. Вам надо только пронумеровать записи в порядке `order by divs, points desc` нумерация выполняется переменными, в том запросе за это отвечают @n для номера и @g что бы помнить последний divs который был, что бы начать отсчет с 1 когда он поменяется. И потом тупо отбираем все записи у которых номера <=3

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecc4d/1  Тот запрос переделанный под вашу таблицу. разница только в замене conat именем вашей колонки divs ну и в сортировке конечно по другим колонкам

Comment: @Mike, Ведь это мне и нужно было!)))
Спасибо огромное!