# Как правильно сформировать запрос к mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть mysql таблица 
`id` | `username` | `number` | `created_at`
1    | valera     | `50`     | 2017-03-19
...
99   | valera     | `30`     | 2017-03-18
...
321  | katya      | `40`     | 2017-03-19
...
444  | katya      | `10`     | 2017-03-17
...
999999 | alesha   | `3`      | 2017-01-12

Нужно получить N-ную запись с конца, всех пользователей.
Пока нашел две реализации, но они не совсем подходят.
1. вариант
Можно получить запись к примеру по дню CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, но нюанс, если пользователь не оставил запись в предыдущий день, то мы не получим данных, а надо если в предпоследний день нет записи, брать еще за более ранний день пока не получим пред последнюю запись пользователя. В день юзер может оставить только 1 запись, либо не оставить вовсе.

SELECT * FROM `content` WHERE and `created_at`=CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY

2. вариант

   - Собираю все `username` за CURRENT_DATE, далее собираю всех у кого больше 2 записей, чтобы быть уверенымы что пред последняя запись существует.
     Далее убираю все `username` не оставлявшие запись сегодня с помощью array_intersect();

И в цикле получаем уже данные за нужный день
$MY_LIMIT = "LIMIT 1, 1";//1 - Номер строки(0-последняя, 1-предпоследняя, 2- третья с конца и т.д.)
$query .= "(SELECT * FROM `content` where `username`='".$uniqum_username."' order by `id` DESC ".$MY_LIMIT.") union ";
$query = substr($query, 0, -7);

Да, этот метод работает мы получаем нужную запись с конца со всех пользователей базы данных. Но он очень, очень ресурсозатратный.
По базе даже в 10к пользователей выполняет выборку 200 секунд что не подходит.

Вот пример данных что нужно получить с учетом того что сегодня 2017-03-19 число данные за предыдущий день. пред последняя запись valera 2017-03-18, а предпоследняя запись katya 2017-03-17.
Есть еще идеи реализации, более шустрые и элегантные?

99 | valera | `30` | 2017-03-18 //Вторая с конца запись юзера Валера
444 | katya | `10` | 2017-03-17 //Вторая с конца запись юзера Катя
...

Заранее благодарен, мозг кипит.

Comment: Вам нужно выполнить нумерацию записей в группе (по юзеру или по юзеру и дате - не очень понял), и взять записи с требуемым номером. FAQ по нумерации записей в группах для MySQL можно посмотреть, например, тут: http://www.sql.ru/forum/684431/faq-numeraciya-strok-i-drugie-voprosy-pro-ispolzovanie-peremennyh

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте что нибудь в этом роде:

```
select C.*
  from content C
  join (
   select (select id from content B
            where B.username=A.username 
            order by username,created_at desc
            limit 1,1
          ) id
     from content A
    group by username
  ) X on C.id=X.id
```

Рекомендуется создать составной индекс из полей `(username, created_at)`. После чего ориентироваться на план выполнения.

Если есть отдельная таблица, содержащая список существующих пользователей (где они уникальны), рекомендуется в подзапросе заменить `content A` на нее и убрать group by.

Comment: [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1ed5/3) в последнее время что-то туго работает. На обед сходил, а тут и ответ сформировался)

Comment: @vp_arth Я в нем обычно только "text to DDL" использую, а потом копирую к себе в MySQL воркшоп (ну или в другую БД, у меня для тестов 5 СУБД стоят :) )

Comment: Я не могу понят ваш запрос может получить N'ую запись?

Comment: @0xdef Ну да, в limit номер записи первым параметром (отсчет с нуля) пишем и все.

Comment: На маленькой базе в 100 строк работает, хорошо. но на 10к строк уже уходит по таймауту 504 :-(

Comment: @Mikhail А вы таблицу внутреннюю на список пользователей заменили ? И конечно надо смотреть план выполнения и на основе него уже решать, что с этим делать. Конечно подзапросы в списке выборки это не хорошо, но надо глянуть что именно они делают (см. explain)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT t1.username, t2.id FROM
 (select max(n-1) as cnt, username from 
    (select id, if(@usr=username,@i:=@i+1,@i:=0) as n, 
        @usr:=username as prevname, username 
    from content order by username, dt) as z group by username
  ) as t1
  LEFT JOIN 
  (select id, if(@usr=username,@i:=@i+1,@i:=0) as n, 
    @usr:=username as prevname, username from content order by username, dt) as t2
 ON t1.username = t2.username and t1.cnt = t2.n;
```

Скорость незнаю какая будет, отпишитесь как попробуете, номер записи указываете вот здесь max(n-**1**) -1 это предпоследняя.

Comment: В данном виде не работает выдает NULL в столбце id http://prntscr.com/en2frw
С нумерацией не приходилось сталкиваться, сейчас буду вникать, спасибо @Akina за ссылку.

Comment: @Mikhail Да, с нумерацией посмотрите, возможно оно будет быстрее других вариантов. И заодно переделайте этот запрос на обратную сортировку (что бы нумеровало записи с конца и тогда сможете жестко брать записи с n=2 и убрать подзапрос получающий количества записей. Что то в этом http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585109/#585127 роде должно получится

Comment: @0xdef что то не работает, помоги допилить http://prnt.sc/expz4s http://prnt.sc/expzaq